# Python Unit Test: mock the function wrapping other function?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

Here is what I want to test:

**test.py**

```
class MyTest(TestCase)

    def test1(self):
        data = crawl_data()

        Check data lengh and current data in DB...

        function2()

        Again, Check data lengh and current data in DB...
```

And program code:

**a.py**

```
def crawl_data():
    """
    crawl data from web
    """
    .
    .
    return web_crawled_data
```

**b.py**

```
from a import crawl_data

def function2():
    """
    crawl data and store new data in database
    """
    .
    .
    result = crawl_data()
    .
    .
    update data and update Database
    .
    .
```

What I want to do is testing `function2()`. Problem is though `function2()` call `crawl_data()` inside.

I don't want `crawl_data()` to crawl data from web in the test, So I tried mocking this function.

```
@patch("a.crawl_data")
def test1(self, crawl_data):
    crawl_data.return_value = [("112233", "ABCDEF"), ("222233", "EFGHIJ")]

    data = crawl_data()

    Check data length and current data in DB

    function2()

    Check the database whether new data stored in DB
```

When I run the test, `function2()` still crawl data from the web in real!

The reason that I don't want to mock function2 is that, when I start the test, test framework use virtual database (provided by `django`)!

So, What I want to do is make `crawl_data()` as a mock when the `function2()` call it inside.

How can I do that?

**EDIT**

I followed the solution "Martijn Pieters♦" gave, and implement code like below:

**a.py**

```
def sum():
    return 1
```

**b.py**

```
from a import sum

def calling_sum():
    return sum()
```

**test1.py**

```
@patch("b.sum")
def test_sum(self, sum):
    sum.return_value = 10
    print(calling_sum())
```

**result**

It print out "1", not 10....

I tried to change `@patch("b.sum")` to `@patch("b.fake_sum")` to check whether it import correctly, and `@patch("b.fake_sum")` occured error(something like `fake_sum not exsits`) so I think `importing module` works well

Still doesn't work..

Comment: Your edit has both the original and the mock return 10. If you are seeing `1` then you are not running the code posted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I edited it!

Comment: What is `b()`? Please, post a proper MCVE, code you actually can copy and run.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Really sorry about making such a mistake T_T

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/f88ee12a72f876f2b52a3983b58287d2 for what your test does. I renamed `a.py` to `foo.py`, and `b.py` to `ham.py` to create a more distinct difference. I also used `mock_foo_bar` as the name for the mock object to be clear that the argument passed in by `patch()` is a mock, not the original. The test shows that the mock is applied correctly. That's because the `ham.bar` reference is the global that `calling_foo_bar()` sees at the time it is called. Your MCVE **can't work differently**. It really does not reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

You are patching the wrong reference to `crawl_data`; the `b` module has a direct reference to the function, which patching `a.crawl_data` won't touch. Patch it in `b`:

```
@patch("b.crawl_data")
def test1(self, crawl_data):
    crawl_data.return_value = [("112233", "ABCDEF"), ("222233", "EFGHIJ")]
```

Also see the [*Where to patch* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) of the `mock` module documentation.

There is no point in using `data = crawl_data()` in your test, there is little point in testing your mock.

Comment: Thanks! but what is the meaning of "There is no point in using `data = crawl_data()` in your test, there is little point in testing your mock."? I'm not native english speaker, so hope explain in easy way please?

Comment: When I follow your advices and run test, mocked `crawled_data.called()` return `False` after calling `function2()` in the test code...and it still crawl data from web.. not mocked!!

Comment: @user3595632: in your question, you have `data = crawl_data()` in your `test1` method, right after the `crawl_data.return_value = [...]` assignment. Why do you call `crawl_data()` there? That's a call to the mock, and that call will always return the list you just assigned to `crawl_data.return_value`. That's not a useful test.

Comment: @user3595632: for your `b.py` module, as shown in the question, `@patch("b.crawl_data")` **does work**, and for the duration of `test1()`, using the name `crawl_data()` in `function2()` **will** call the mock. Perhaps you have not accurately recreated your actual situation?

Comment: @Martjin Pieters : I edited the post. Please check that out